Uploading file via Netsuite to Devops
I have been trying to upload a file as an attached at Devops using User Event, I have encoded the contents from UTF_8 to BASE_64 and in the header object the content type is "application/octet-stream" but due to some reason the files get corrupted midway and I am not able to view them at Devops but they do get attached there. Are there any issues with the encoding? Also the normal txt files get uploaded but other ones do not get uploaded. I am assuming it has something to do with the the contents of file.

You might want to add some details about what you've tried.
First though review my answer on this post: In NetSuite with SuiteScript 2.0 unable to send a file with HTTP POST request with a content-type multipart/form-data to see if that answers your question
